# Do canned responses only work in a certain versions of GMail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-canned-response

Do canned responses only work in a certain versions of GMail? I do not seem to have the canned responses icon even after I enable it in labs

Comment: They're rolling out a new Compose window, but I don't think it's universal yet. From what country are you accessing Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

Canned Responses don't have an icon - they show up a regular link below the subject line.

[image]